# How do you format the set_body option for WP_Rest_Request?

Tags: rest-api

I am looking to pull data from a Google Spreadsheet using SpreadAPI.

This is my current code.

```php
$request = new WP_REST_Request('POST', 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/UNIQUE_CODE/exec');

$request->setBody('{\n"method": "GET",\n"sheet": "date",\n"key": "ACCESS_KEY"\n}');

$response = rest_do_request( $request );
```

However I'm clearly doing something wrong when it comes to formatting the setBody option. I'm not getting a json response, and I can't seem to find any examples of this in the WordPress documentation.

The call works fine when I put it into the RAW section in Postman like this. I'm just not sure how to do that using WordPress.

```
{
"method": "GET",
"sheet": "date",
"key": "ACCESS_KEY"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WP_Rest_Request` is not a way to make outgoing calls to remote REST APIs, it's a data object core uses to pass around information about an incoming request. It's basically something you recieved, it isn't something you can send.

If you poke your sites REST API with a request, WordPress creates and populates a `WP_Rest_Request` object and uses it to help handle the request.

So you cannot use this class to make requests to Google.

For that, you want to use the  WP_HTTP APIs, such as `wp_remote_get`, or `wp_remote_post`.

Comment: Thank You! Lots of resources for this exact thing. It makes a lot more sense. I'm currently following the code examples here - https://konstantin.blog/2011/a-note-on-wp_http-and-http-requests-in-wordpress/